# Installing Perl module on cygwin (make failed)

Tags: perl, module, makefile, cygwin

I need `Digest::SHA1` for a Perl script that I'd like to run on cygwin. However, I have to configure it using CPAN. Everything seems fine until I run `cpan[1]> install Digest::SHA1`.
Stuff goes on, then I'm given the following error:

> /bin/sh: gcc-4: command not found
>   Makefile:327: recipe for target `SHA1.o' failed
>   make: *** [SHA1.o] Error 127
>   GAAS/Digest-SHA1-2.13.tar.gz
>   /usr/bin/make -- NOT OK
>   'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
>   Running make test
>   Can't test without successful make 
>   Running make install
>   Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
>   Failed during this command:
>   GAAS/Digest-SHA1-2.13.tar.gz                 : make NO

It seems like I must have gcc4 installed. The make error is not because of its path because it's set up correctly (`o conf make` in CPAN returns `/usr/bin/make` and I have `make`'s binaries installed.). Unfortunately cygwin doesn't provide gcc4 package (it's marked as an obsolete package). Is there any workaround to fix this? Or is there a way I can compile gcc4 under cygwin, because simply chaning `gcc-4` to `gcc` in the `Makefile` did not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, you must use the same compiler for XS that was used to compile Perl. You can try to force the one you have and see what happens:

```
cpan> look Digest::SHA1
Digest-SHA1-2.13$ perl Makefile.PL CC=/usr/bin/gcc LD=/usr/bin/gcc
Digest-SHA1-2.13$ make ; make test ; make install
```

Comment: I've `cd`'d in the directory, then ran `perl Makefile.PL CC=/usr/bin/gcc`. Then the `Makefile` was written, and so was `MYMETA.yml`. `make install` gave me the following output: http://pastebin.com/jgnKLnXB. Any ideas?

Comment: The linker also needs to be changed. I have updated the answer above. Please also run `make test`, it is important! It will tell you right away whether this little experiment worked or not. If it worked, you can [change the CPAN configuration `makepl_arg` and `mbuildpl_arg`](http://p3rl.org/CPAN#Config-Variables) to make this permanent.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `perl Makefile.PL CC=/usr/bin/gcc` did not work for me, since the Makefile contained also a plain non-aliased `gcc-4` (Makefile of the Template toolkit)

I simply used 
    cp /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4

Probably `ln` could have worked as well.